# footer menu changes primary menu

Tags: theme-development

I am getting a strange error on my wordpress

My primary menu is changing along with footer menu. so if I remove pages from footer they get remove from Primary menu is aswell

here is how I registered my menu on functions.php

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'mytheme' ),
        'footer' => esc_html__( 'Footer Menu', 'mytheme' ),
    ) );
```

footer.php

```
  <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(
        array (
            'theme-location' => 'footer',
            'container' => 'nav'
       ) 
    ); 
?>
```

and header.php

```
 <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(
        array (
            'theme-location' => 'primary',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'navbar',
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'
       ) 
    ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your argument is wrong](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters). It is `theme_location` not `theme-location`. The underscore matters.

Also, what you are doing with [`esc_html__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_2) is overly complicated. You aren't passing HTML through the function, and I am fairly sure you never should pass HTML for this, just a string. All you need is [`__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)